# An error "ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8"

Tags: java-8, dockerfile, openstreetmap, docker-machine

I was trying to build my docker image to use it for converting OSM to MATSim. But when I run the command docker build . -t osm-to-matsim ., it gives me an error:

```
[+] Building 3.2s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                    0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 263B                                    0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                       0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                         0.0s 
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8         2.9s
 => [auth] library/java:pull token for registry-1.docker.io             0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/java:8:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: docker.io/library/java:8: not found
```

The Dockerfile is shown like this:

```
FROM java:8
RUN mkdir /osm2matsim
WORKDIR /osm2matsim

COPY . . 
RUN javac -cp vendor/matsim-0.9.0/matsim-0.9.0.jar Osm2matsim.java

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "vendor/matsim-0.9.0/matsim-0.9.0.jar:.", "Osm2matsim"]
```

Comment: Hey, did you find any answers to this?